# DirectShow Raw Capture

Tags: c++, directshow

I have problems with DirectShow. I'm trying to record video from webcam and save as raw format on the disk. Can someone PLEASE show me simple example how to do it? I'm new to it and I'm not having enough time to start learning and then doing it, because of job..

Thank you!

Comment: What have you got so far? What are the specific problems?

Comment: Tried all the ways what I've found in google, but none of them works as I expected. Some APIs are deprecated and I don't know what else should I do.. I just need an sample of this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DirectShow Samples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- AmCap Sample     Capture Video capture application.
- PlayCap Sample   Capture Simple capture application.

Using GraphEdit SDK tool you can interactively connect web cam filter to [WM ASF Writer Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and produce Windows Media files (the same can be repeated in code programmatically).

Comment: AmCap and PlayCap uses a lot of deprecated methods + it's not recording in RAW format :(

Comment: On the one hand the whole DirectShow is deprecated. However, it is still the most powerful video API in Windows. You can record raw with all the same methods AmCap uses and demonstrates.